# How do I get the dropdown value from within the FancyBox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox-2

I have been researching and now need some input.  Would someone show me the tweak that'll make this code display the dropdown value in the alert?  It currently displays as "undefined" while the textbox value displays correctly.  Thanks.

file1.ftl

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>
    <button id="displayFancyboxButton">Display Fancybox</button>
    <#include "file2.ftl">
</body>
</html>
```

file2.ftl

```
<div id="theContents" style="display:none">
    <input id="textboxId" type="text" />
    <select id="dropdownId">
        <option value="Select">Select</option>
        <option value="first">one</option>
        <option value="second">two</option>
        <option value="third">three</option>
    </select>
    <button id="displayButtonId" id="save">Display</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#displayFancyboxButton').click(function(){
        $.fancybox.open({
            content: $('#theContents').html()
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("body").on("click","button[id=displayButtonId]",function(){
        var textboxVal = $('.fancybox-inner input[id="textboxId"]').val();
        var dropdownVal = $('.fancybox-inner input[id="dropdownId"]').val();
        alert('textboxVal=' + textboxVal + ", dropdownVal=" + dropdownVal);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the selector to this:

```
var dropdownVal = $('#dropdownId').val();
```

The route you were taking would have needed to end up like this:

```
var dropdownVal = $('.fancybox-inner select[id="dropdownId"]').val();
```

The selector needed to be **select**[id="dropdownId"] and not input[id="dropdownId"] because you were working with a select tag instead of an input tag.

However, this approach is a bit convoluted. Because dropDownId is a unique id on the page, your selector only needs to reference it and not fancybox-inner or select/input.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks Woodifer.  I agree this code is a bit convoluted but that's because it's stripped down to demo the problem from a larger context.  The larger context is what caused me to use "fancybox-inner" rather than just $('#dropdownId') which I had working.  I actually tried "selected" rather than "select".  Argh.  So close.  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Woodifer this helped me lot.